# How to return to the GUI?

Tags: lightdm, gui

I am very new to Linux and Ubuntu. I use Ubuntu 11.10.

I was trying to exit the X server (in order to install some Nvidia drivers) and I typed in the terminal:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

How can I return to the Ubuntu interface?

Answer (score 4):

You can run the opposite command:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Login using your credentials. Type in:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Then press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.