# Cant shut down X-windows with out system hanging

Tags: 12.10, drivers, nvidia

I need to install my video drivers, in order to do so I have to shut down X-windows, but it hangs every time and will not go all the way out to prompt.

I'm using `sudo init 1`

I used a couple of other commands as well for this purpose with the same problem.  Any ideas?

Running 12.10 64bit

Comment: This is the correct method: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116830/returning-to-the-gui (bottom answer;use stop instead of start to stop x-server).

Answer (score 1):

Pres `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, login with your account, run following code:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
```

After you did your job run following to start X-Window again:

```
sudo service lightdm start
```

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 and newer. `sudo service gdm stop` or `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop` for older releases.

Comment: I have a same issue as the OP, on Ubuntu 12.04. Indeed, `sudo service lightdm stop`, from a text terminal (from the graphic terminal, it hangs) do work. However, `sudo init 1` should work, or else at least, there should be something telling the user it's not implemented or not working as expected (the same when trying to shutdown `lightdm` from a graphic terminal).

Comment: I also just checked changing the default runlevel to 1 (setting `DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL` in `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`), does not work: no terminal after the boot, and I had to Ctrl‑Alt‑Suppr to reboot and restore the default runlevel from a rescue CD.